# How to connect Options Menu with Navigation Components

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-architecture-navigation, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to learn Navigation Components and I've stuck with implementing Options Menu. I have one simple options item called "settings" and it navigates to the "SettingsFragment". I implemented it following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer) but the menu item is not displayed in the toolbar with this way.

Here is my MainActivity code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NavController navController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NavHostFragment hostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(hostFragment);

        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
                new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
                toolbar,
                navController,
                appBarConfiguration
        );
     
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

However, when I set toolbar with `setSupportActionBar()` in advance and then use `NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController()` instead of `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController()` it seems to be working, I can see the options menu and the navigation function also works but I lose nice little toolbar animations also I don't know if its the best practice. I am new with this topic so I want to know what am I missing or how can I implement it correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
 new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_history, R.id.nav_service).build();
 
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

Comment: Can you give me a bit more information about this solution? I could not understand it,. Thank you.